How to move a chat under another stackexchange site?
I wanted to open this chat under mathoverflow but instead it got opened under stackoverflow. How can I move it under mathoverflow?

well, it's, empty, so the easiest method would be to head over to mathoverflow's chat server and create it again. if there is a way to move a room from A to B it would involve devs and not be worth it for a room with no history. The one on SO will close itself in a week or so.

@KevinB and the only way to delete it is avoid posting and waiting a week right?

Correct. As long as it stays empty (which you can enforce as the RO by timing it out or making it request only) it'll go away entirely eventually

MO's under a different chat server from SO. I think you can re-parent a site in the same server, but you can't re-parent a SO chatroom on the SO server to another site

Apparently someone have now moved it under mathoverflow.

@JourneymanGeek It is possible to have rooms parented to SO or Meta.SE on Chat.SE.

@KevinB Mods of the room's current chat parent site can reparent rooms.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Yes, which is why I said SO chatroom, and SO server, I tried my best to be sufficiently pedantic

The commenters' advice is generally right: for an empty room, just leaving it where it is and recreating it makes the most sense. It will expire automatically in time.
I don't think users can reparent chatrooms from one chat server to another. (There are some invisible barriers between certain sites that, by memory, prevent regular users from migrating chatrooms between specific parent sites.)
But... I can do it. It's fast, it's easy, I did it.

For context, reparenting can be done by mods of the site of the room's current chat parent.

Thank you, it's strange because when I first created it I started at mathoverflow, it seems to me that the system chose automatically stackoverflow, but I could have made an error in the process as well, not 100% sure.

huh... i didn't expect chat to have this feature, especially from one chat sever to another

@KevinB To be honest, I didn't expect it to be able to do it correctly either. But I realized... I'd never had to pay attention to which chat server I'm migrating a room to before. Frankly, half of me just wanted to try it to see what would happen.

@KevinB There was no chat server migration here. The room was on the same server, Chat.SE - it was just parented to SO (which is possible, along with Meta.SE as a parent).

@Slate playground 101! (but yeah, win win situation. :))
